# How to open a link tags in tab control using cefsharp?

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I just developed an application like a web browser with the use of Cefsharp library in windows form application. My browser has got several tabs, but whenever user clicks on 'a link tags' with the property of _blank the application opens a new link in a separated window although I want to open links in a new tab in tab control instead.

what I used for my application:

- C# windows form application
- ChromiumWebBrowser class from Cefsharp library

I would be pleased if anyone can help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just looked through the documentation and found out the issue.

- you need to use the **LifeSpanHandler** class to interrupt the popup and disable opening new browsers by assigning  newBrowser to 'null' then you'll be able to perform your instructions.
- If you want your windows open in self tab, just remove the comment in below code.

Here's what I've done for my problem:

```
 public class LifespanHandler : ILifeSpanHandler
    {

        bool ILifeSpanHandler.OnBeforePopup(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string targetUrl, string targetFrameName, WindowOpenDisposition targetDisposition, bool userGesture, IPopupFeatures popupFeatures, IWindowInfo windowInfo, IBrowserSettings browserSettings, ref bool noJavascriptAccess, out IWebBrowser newBrowser)
        {

            Program.Form.Invoke(new Action(() => Program.Form.newPage(targetUrl)));

            //browser.MainFrame.LoadUrl(targetUrl);

            newBrowser = null;
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Hope this is useful for you. :)